# How do I combine geometries in a shapefile based on a grouping variable?

Tags: r, sf

Here is a simple example. I have a shapefile of three US states:

[image: Three US states]

This is the code that creates the shapefile.

```
library(USAboundaries)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

states <- us_states(map_date = "2000-01-01", resolution = "high", states = c("CA", "OR", "WA")) %>%
  mutate(group_var = if_else(state_abbr == "CA", 1, 2))
plot(st_geometry(states))
```

Now, I'm trying to combine the geometries based on the value of `group_var`, so California should stand alone while Oregon and Washington get lumped together into a single geometry. Unfortunately, `st_combine` doesn't take a grouping variable, and although the [`aggregate`](https://rdrr.io/cran/sf/man/aggregate.sf.html) function in `sf` looks promising, code like this throws an error that `group_var` cannot be found.

```
x <- aggregate(states, group_var, mean)
```

Furthermore, `aggregate` requires a function as a third argument, presumably because `aggregate` in the `stats` package applies the function to the data, but in this case, there isn't any data to apply a function to. I'm just trying to combine/aggregate the shapefiles.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could also do this using `dplyr`'s `group_by()` and `summarize()` functions:

```
states %>%
  group_by(group_var) %>% 
  summarize(geometry = st_union(geometry))
```

Comment: This is great; thank you. Since I'm more familiar with `dplyr`, this is much more intuitive to me.

Answer (score 5):

You were close; just cast the second argument in `aggregate()` as a list, like this:

```
x <- aggregate(states, 
               by = list(states$group_var),
               FUN = mean)

x
plot(x)
```

Comment: This is brilliant; thank you! Out of curiosity, what is the `mean` function actually taking the mean over if there is no non-geometric data in the data frame?

Comment: Running `x` suggests that factors get turned into `NA`'s.

Answer (score 3):

You could also simplify [Chris Merkord's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/316473/107424) with:
`states %>% group_by(group_var) %>%  summarize()`

Answer (score 3):

You are basically describing a dissolve operation. This can easily be done using the rgeos package. Note that I switched datasets because I was having difficulty installing the USAboundaries and USAboundariesData packages.

```
library(rgeos)
library(sp)
library(spData)
library(rgdal)

columbus <- rgdal::readOGR(system.file("shapes/columbus.shp", 
                           package="spData")[1])
   print(columbus$NSB)
     plot(columbus)

diss <- rgeos::gUnaryUnion(columbus, id = columbus$NSB)
  plot(diss, col=c("red","green"))
    plot(columbus, add=TRUE)
```

For a more modern interface using sf the equivalent is `sf::st_union`. Keep in mind that the default precision can have an effect on how internal boundaries are resolved. This can be changed using something like: `sf::st_set_precision(1e8)`

Comment: small typo: `plot(Columbus)` should be `plot(columbus)`!?